# Trouble understanding the output of this regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to catch all hexadecimal colors in a string literal. I'm using Python 3, and that's what I have:

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"#[a-fA-F\d]{3}([a-fA-F\d]{3})?")
```

However, when I apply the `findall` regex method on `#abcdef` here's what I get:

```py
>>> re.findall(pattern,"#abcdef") 
["def"]
```

Can someone explain me why do I have that? I actually need to get `["#abcdef"]`
Thank you in advance

Comment: regex will return capturing group - in your case last three characters. Try change it to non-capturing group `re.compile(r"#[a-fA-F\d]{3}(?:[a-fA-F\d]{3})?")`

Comment: Looks like it worked to me. What output did you want?

Comment: @Andrej Kesely is right, if there are any capture groups in the regexp it will not return the full matches, only the capture groups' contents.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks a lot for helping me. Do I have to mark this post as solved? (I am new here)

Comment: Best would be if Andrej posted his comment as an answer so you could accept that..

Comment: More discussion here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1558/297001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Andrej Kesely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035985/andrej-kesely), I got the answer to my question, that is:

> Regex will return capturing group.

To bypass this, just change the regex from:

```
r"#[a-fA-F\d]{3}([a-fA-F\d]{3})?"
```

to:

```
r"#[a-fA-F\d]{3}(?:[a-fA-F\d]{3})?"
```

Comment: By default, it populates the result array with each whole match. If you have capture groups, it populates the result with just the capture groups and not the whole match.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://regex101.com:
[image: Regex Description]

It looks like this regex is looking for

#(three characters a through f, A through F or a digit)(three characters a through f, A through F or a digit, which may or may not be present, and if they are they are what is returned from the match)

If you are looking to match any instance of the whole above string, I would recommend this instead:

`#[a-fA-F\d]{6}`
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. However, I also need to search for colors like #fff, that's why it must be 3 characters long or 6.